# Effect of silencer in Crysis 2

Tags: crysis-2

When attaching the silencer to the scarab or the M12, does it have any effect other than making the enemies not notice me? Does it decrease accuracy or firepower? Do I have a reason to take it off my weapon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Crysis 1, when the silencer is used, the damage reduction over distance is greatly increased. So in close range using the silencer should be as effective as not using it, but it quickly becomes less and less effective.

From forum posts and wikis, it seems that it behaves the same in Crysis 2.

Comment: One another thing that I noticed now is that when using reflex sight and the silencer the muzzle flash will get in your way, I don't know whether it's a bug or by design that way.